# Why is the following function returning NULL given non-null inputs and when it should return a vector of processed inputs?

Tags: r, broom

I have a function that is passed a list of formulas and a list of data sets. I want to take every data set and build a model using the associated formula (the inputs are in the same order and the same length so they line up). I will then return a list of the models for each formula-data pair. For some reason my function is returning `NULL` and I can't figure out why. I suspect that scoping does not work the way I think it does. The code is rather short so here it is:

```
models_from_formula <- function(formulas, subsets) {
  out <- c()
  mapply(function(f, s) {
    out <- c(out, glance(lm(f, data = s)))
  }, formulas, subsets)

  out
}
```

It should call my function with every pair of formula and data-set. I then create a model, use `broom::glance()` to get the information I care about, and then add it to the vector that holds my output. Somehow `out` becomes `NULL` and never changes... any ideas?

Comment: You do not have to initialise `out` and call `out` at the end of your function to output the results of mapply. Secondly, without a reproducible example, it will be tricky for someone to understand where NULL arrives from.

Comment: agree with @Ali about a [mcve]. Also, `c()` may not combine the results of `glance` the way you expect. I would recommend something like `purrr::map2_dfr(formulas, subsets, ~glance(lm(.x,data=.y))` ...

Comment: @BenBolker Your example gets me closer to what I'm trying to get. Is there a way that instead of getting one dataframe with many rows of results I can get a list with each element of the list being a dataframe with a single row? I know that is a dumb way to do it but I'm required to do it that way.

Comment: I think you can just use `map2` instead of `map2_dfr`

Comment: @BenBolker That works! Thank you! I will answer my own question when I have time. It may be a day or two before I can take the time to write out a proper answer.